# React / Unit testing: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'buttonGroup')

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Need help to undrstand why my test stop working.

Using React + Jest + React testing lib

this is test:

```
  it('renders all buttons correctly', () => {
    render(<ButtonGroup {...buttonGroupDefaultProps} />);

    expect(screen.getByText(/first/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/second/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/third/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'buttonGroup')

  38 | describe('ButtonGroup tests', () => {
  39 |   it('renders all buttons correctly', () => {
> 40 |     render(<ButtonGroup {...buttonGroupDefaultProps} />);
     |     ^
  41 |
  42 |     expect(screen.getByText(/first/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  43 |     expect(screen.getByText(/second/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

  at useCompo
```

Any comment is welcome

Comment: Did you import the component in your file ?

Comment: This question is missing info, show us ButtonGroup definition?